# Changing the language setting of the FileUpload UserControl

Tags: c#, internationalization, webusercontrol

How do I change the language setting of the FileUpload UserControl.

The button keeps saying "Browse", no matter which language I have set.

I have the rest of the site working in the selected language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant change the FileUpload button text from server, the language is set by the OS, for this you'll need to use a JS file uploader like [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)